# Late 70’s early 80’s horror where time pauses and exploding light bulb restarts it

Tags: story-identification, movie

This film had a woman going into a bar and time freezes, light bulb explodes and brings her out of pause. Bald bad guy sees her and gives chase, she escapes but during the film time keeps stopping...

Not sure of year ..I thought bad guy was Robert Tessier, but nothing in his filmography.

The setting was a big American city, I saw it on the TV, could have a been TV film. It stuck in my mind because of the interesting idea of everyone just stopping. It was a similar idea to *Cashback*.

Comment: Do you mean that time is literally freezing (as in *some kind of temporal effect*)?

Comment: Where did you see this? Movie theater, television, video rental? What was the setting, big city, small town, desert? I need a few more details.

Comment: The setting was a big American city, I saw it on the tv, could have a been tv film..it stuck in my mind because of the interesting idea of everyone just stopping. It was a similar idea to Cashback.

Answer (score 3):

[*Mind Over Murder*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079559/) (1979 TV movie)

This was a television movie released at the right time and starred a bald villain played by Andrew Prine. Below is the plot summary from IMDb.com.

> A young woman begins to have nightmares where she believes that time stands still and she can see and hear future events. In her nightmares she keeps seeing an evil bald man. Her doctor can't figure out what is happening, but a government agent who hears about her visions tries to help her, as he is investigating a plane crash that appears to involve the bald man she keeps seeing.

Here is the full movie from YouTube. I scanned through it and I think I found the bar scene at 5 minutes in, but I didn't see the exploding light bulb.